# Can't debug Canvas in xaml on visual studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, ironpython

all

I am begginer of python,but I have expererience to use c#
so, I tried to use ironpython WPF on visual studio.
then, when I tried to debug using Canvas in xaml, 
a bit of time, screen begin to debug, but after that,
screen go back to coding screen.no debug.
why is this happenning?
if you have knowledge about this, please teach me.

here is the coding screen

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
Title="WpfApplication1" Height="300" Width="300"> 


Content="Let's Begin"
HorizontalAlignment="Left"
VerticalAlignment="Top"
Margin="90,115,0,0" 
Click="Button_Click" />
```

thanks

Tomfin

Comment: Any exception thrown ? If u mean that that VS takes u back to code editor,an exception must be thrown, what is it ?

Comment: your code sample is incomplete. but you can't put a string into a canvas content.... try <canvas><canvas.content><TextBlock>test<TextBlock/></canvas.content>   then you have to locate it by X/Y

Comment: @zack raiyan
thanks for reply
there is noexception, just go back to screen before debug

Comment: @GCamel,thanks for play. I changed to your sample code but, as canvas.content is not exist. and I add width and heght to my code, but same problem happen.